# DataGrid Library: I need to know the callback success function where I can get response of my API call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datagrid

I did R&D on datagrid Library but was not able to find the callback success function for the url passed in one of the parameter saveURL.[image]

This is  what i am receiving in response:
[image]